# Is there a way to give the user Owner role in subscription scope, but deny/read access to resource groups not made by him?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-policy, azure-rbac, azure-role-environment

I want to invite guest user in Azure with permissions that he could do whatever he wants in subscription scope with owner role, but he couldn't view other resource groups that he didn't make or just be able to read them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently that's not possible. [Deny assigments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/deny-assignments) are limited to a couple of resource types.